# what is Virtualization kvm vnet1 and vnet2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-10.04

please any one can advice what is vnet1 and vnet2 in kvm Virtualization as iam using host ubuntu 10.04 LTS

as i have a bridge and everything is running perfect but when i did the command brctl show
i got the following results

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.d067e5fb7dec   no      eth0
                            vnet0
                            vnet1
                            vnet2
br2     8000.d067e5fb7dee   no      eth1
virbr0      8000.000000000000   yes
```

and when i execute the command ifconfig i got the vnet1 and vnet2 and  vnet0 in the result can anyone advice what is it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vnet* are the virtual interfaces of the VMs. You can configure their names (numbers) otherwise QEMU just counts them up.

These virtual interfaces are bridged to either physical or virtual interfaces on the host. You can have a look at what the VM sees on that interface by

```
tcpdump -i vnet0 -n
```